# Testing divs exist with Jasmine,Webpack and vue.js

Tags: jasmine, vue.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, bdd

In my vue component I have code that conditionally renders a div:

```
  <div v-if="successCriteria()" id="success">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
  <Commit-chart :data="chartOptions" ></Commit-chart>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div v-else>
There has been an error with rendering.
</div>
</div>
```

and I am trying to test this using jasmine. For example, when the success criteria is met, the success div is present. here is my test:

```
describe('Graph Tests', () => {
const getComponent = (prop1,prop2) =>{
  let vm = new Vue({
    template: '<div><graph ref="graph" :label=prop1 :data=prop2></graph></div>',
    components: {
      graph,
    },

  })
  return vm;
}    



 it('Renders correctly with valid props', () => {
          const label = ['j', 'a' ,'c', 'k'];
          const data=[1,2,3,4]
          var vm = getComponent(label,data).$mount();
          console.info(vm.$refs.graph.$el);
          expect(vm.$refs.graph.$el.querySelector('success')).toBeTruthy();
        });

        });

    }
```

When I log vm.$refs.graph.$el I get:

```
INFO: <!---->
```

in the console which I am very confused about.  Can anyone help me get the div with id "success" ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for an id of "success" is `'#success'`. Or you can use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

However, the output from your program indicates the component is not rendering at all.